# Gatsby GraphQL custom date formatString

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby, date-formatting, template-literals

I have this:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allMdx(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "DD 'de'  MMMM, YYYY", locale: "pt")
            title
            description
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

in the line ->> 

`date(formatString: "DD 'de'  MMMM, YYYY", locale: "pt")`

I have to insert strings but this 'de' isnt working. I know I want to display the date like:

`25 de March, 2020.`

But the result is:

`25 '32' March, 2020.`

I know this isnt working, i know why, but I can't make it right.
I'm Using Gatsbyjs with graphql

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gatsby relies on [moment.js to format dates](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format).

> To escape characters in format strings, you can wrap the custom string in square brackets.

```
date(formatString: "DD [de]  MMMM, YYYY", locale: "pt")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Simple Put**

date(formatString: "DD MMMM, YYYY")

`Output Like this: 04 February, 2021`

Comment: here in brazil we actually use the output format of dates kinda like this:
02 of February, 2021 (for instance... but thanks a lot either way :D)